# How to create a connectionstring without using the admin

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to connect to my database from my website without using an admin account.  I would prefer a user with a role that has limited access CRUD and Procs but without the ability to modify much else.

- I am using SQL Server.
- I am building everything in C#.NET.
- I am using SQL Server Object Explorer and T-SQL to manipulate the database.

I can create a user and password in the `DatabaseServer.Security` folder.
But I can only create a role in the `DatabaseServer.Databases.MyDatabase.Security`
I can only assign a user created in the `DatabaseServer.Databases.MyDatabase.Security` to this role.

The users in the `DatabaseServer` security have a password but those in the `Database.Security` don't seem to have a password (or way to login).

Answer (score 2):

You need to map a login to a user.

```
ALTER USER <your user name>
           WITH login = <your login name>;
```

For more information see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).